# Make a fixed bar above the footer

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a fixed bar above the footer that says something like: "This site is in beta. Please send feedback to info@blah.com."

I'm new to CSS and struggling with this.

Here's my footer CSS:

```
#footer {
  min-height: 60px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4d4d4d), to(#333333));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4d4d4d', endColorstr='#333333', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #424242;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4d4d4d), to(#333333));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d, #333333);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4d4d4d', endColorstr='#333333', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  height: 40px;
}
#footer a {
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  text-decoration: none;
}
#footer span {
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin-left: .5em;
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px
}
#footer-inner {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Basically I want just a small little bar above it that is fixed to the footer and that doesn't screw up the formatting of my footer.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't say something about your HTML mark up, I've created something from scratch.

You can set the position of `#footer` to *relative* and then create an element, that is positioned *absolutely* with a negative `top`-value. So it will always stick on top of the footer and won't affect the footer itself and neither the content above:

**HTML**

```
<footer id="footer">
    <aside>This site is beta</aside>
    Footer
</footer>​
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
}

#footer > aside {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -50px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Here is a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uRba/).